# OpenCV C++: declaring a new variable leads to stack corruption

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been looking through this code for the last two days, and I have no idea what's happenning.

```
void filterKeypoints(std::vector<KeyPoint> &keypoints, Mat orientation){
    unsigned int rows = orientation.rows;
    unsigned int cols = orientation.cols;
    unsigned int N = keypoints.size();

    Mat newOrientation;
    vector<KeyPoint> newKeyPoints;

    // Function do create n points in a interval equally spaced
    vector<float> t = divideInterval(-3.14159265, 3.14159265, 6);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        Mat x_c, y_c;
        getKeyPoint(keypoints[i], x_c, y_c);

        float radius_sq = (72 * pow(keypoints[i].size, 2));
        float radius = 6 * sqrt(2)*keypoints[i].size;

        float x_min = round(keypoints[i].pt.x - radius);
        float x_max = round(keypoints[i].pt.x + radius);
        float y_min = round(keypoints[i].pt.y - radius);
        float y_max = round(keypoints[i].pt.y + radius);
        cout << i << " of " << N << endl;

        if ((x_min >= 0) && (x_max < cols) && (y_min >= 0) && (y_max < rows)){

            Mat X, Y;
            meshGrid(X, Y, x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max);

            X = X.reshape(0, 1); // row vector
            Y = Y.reshape(0, 1);

            int nr = y_max - y_min + 1;
            int nc = x_max - x_min + 1;

            Mat D_array = Mat::zeros(128, 1, CV_32FC1);
            float radius_sq_small = radius_sq / 16;

            //////////// HERE STOPED IMPLEMENTATION
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 16; j++){
                Mat X_sq, Y_sq;
                cv::pow(X - (float) x_c.at<float>(j), 2, X_sq);
                cv::pow(Y - (float) y_c.at<float>(j), 2, Y_sq);
                Mat Distance_Square = X_sq + Y_sq;

                Mat If = Mat::zeros(rows, cols, CV_8UC1);
                Mat Binary;
                //cv::compare(Distance_Square, radius_sq_small, Binary, CMP_LE);

                //Mat Binary = Distance_Square <= radius_sq_small;
                //Binary = Binary.reshape(0, nr);
                //Mat roi_img(If(cvRect(x_min, y_min, nc, nr)));
                //Binary.copyTo(roi_img);


            }

        }

    }

    cout << "Everything run well." << endl;
}
```

If the line where `Mat Binary` is created is uncommented, the program breaks with an unhandled exception: it runs the for cycle, gets to cout and doesn't get out of the void function launching an error: ".exe stopped working".

If I commment this line everything goes as expected. So I am guessing there's some kind of stack corruption, but I am not understanding quite well why...

Note: The function is not all implemented yet, I am just not sure why this error is thrown.

The keypoints come from opencv sift and orientation is an image with gradient orientation. I am using opencv 3.1

The original function that calls it is:

```
void getImageDescriptors(Mat image, Mat orientation){
    cv::Ptr<Feature2D> f2d = xfeatures2d::SIFT::create();
    std::vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
    f2d->detect(image, keypoints);
    Mat descriptors;
    f2d->compute(image, keypoints, descriptors);

    adjustAngle(keypoints);
    filterKeypoints(keypoints, orientation);
    cout << "Got here Correctly" << endl;
}
```

Hope anyone can help me!

Best Regards.

**EDIT 1:**

Here's the getKeyPoint function, that applies some expressions accordingly to the article i'm trying to implement. It never returns an error so I don't thing it comes from here.

```
void getKeyPoint(KeyPoint keypoint, Mat &x_c, Mat &y_c){
    float xc_array[16] = { -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5, -1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5 };
    x_c = Mat(1, 16, CV_32FC1, &xc_array).clone();
    float yc_array[16] = { -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -1.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, -0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5, 1.5 };
    y_c = Mat(1, 16, CV_32FC1, &yc_array).clone();

    float SBP = 3 * keypoint.size;
    float c = cos(keypoint.angle * 3.14159265 / 180);  // Convert to radians
    float s = sin(keypoint.angle * 3.14159265 / 180);

    x_c = SBP*(c*x_c - s*y_c) + keypoint.pt.x; // See this in future
    y_c = SBP*(s*x_c + c*y_c) + keypoint.pt.y;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

By replacing `Mat Binary;` by `Mat Binary = Mat::zeros(Distance_Square.rows, Distance_Square.cols, CV_8UC1);`, the error goes away (creating a matrix of zeros, instead of just default initialization).

My question is, why this variable was messing up the memory allocation and the other ones like newOrientation, X_sq, Y_sq were not causing any trouble?

Comment: What does `getKeyPoint` do?

Comment: What's your building environment? How do you link OpenCV libraries?

Comment: @NathanOliver I edited my answer with the code. It applies some expressions based on the article i'm following, but it does not get any error in my debug.

Comment: @k_kaz I am using cmake.

Comment: Without knowing OpenCV `x_c = SBP*(c*x_c - s*y_c) + keypoint.pt.x;`  looks like you are assigning to a temporary that goes out of scope.

Comment: @NathanOliver Outside the function, x_c and y_c have the desired values, and by applying clone() function I am copying the content of the variable and assigning it to x_c and y_c that are passed by reference. So although it goes out of scope, it still retains its value since I cloned the content of the Mat structure.

Comment: "the program breaks with an unhandled expression" -- huh? Did you mean an **exception**? What does the debugger tell you?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved, thank you to everyone who helped. Basically not all paths of divideInterval function returned a value, so when deallocating memory it thrown an exception. It was a stupid implementation error that I passed by.

Still I do not know why the error was thrown only sometimes.